# Carga denegada por X-Frame-Options: “SAMEORIGIN”

Tags: .htaccess, joomla3, cms

Buen día a todos. Bien tengo el siguiente problema: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El enlace que subraye de color negro es externo a mi sitio principal pero necesito utilizar sus elementos para poder mostrar el formulario de registro en dispositivos móviles, cabe recalcar que antes no tenia ningún problema ya que el formulario se visualizaba todo sin ningún problema.

Ahora bien el subrayado de color verde es mi sitio principal es un cms para ser más especifico, el cual yo tengo control sobre el archivo de .htaccess por ende intente colocar la siguiente regla:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

También sé que solo existe dos posibles formas que son

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, también no sé si sea problema de alguna actualización del enlace externo.

Código adicional:

```
<iframe onload="iFrameHeight(this)" id="blockrandom-332"
name=""
src="https://www.e-tsejemplo.com"
width="100%"
height="550"
scrolling="auto"
frameborder="0"
title="Motormobil En"
class="wrapper   hidden-desktop" >
No iframes</iframe>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo tienes el código en tu página? El problema parece ser la forma en la que estableces el atributo `src` del elemento `frame` en cuestión.

Comment: Claro que sí. 
<iframe onload="iFrameHeight(this)" id="blockrandom-332"
 name=""
 src="https://www.e-tsejemplo.com"
 width="100%"
 height="550"
 scrolling="auto"
 frameborder="0"
 title="Motormobil En"
 class="wrapper   hidden-desktop" >
 No iframes</iframe>

Comment: Agrega eso a tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit]. Mientras preparo una respuesta.

Comment: Ya lo he agregado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema es de concepto. La cabecera *HTTP* [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) se utiliza para indicarle al navegador si la página que está siendo solicitada (alojada en el Servidor A) puede o no ser renderizada en un marco de tipo [`frame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/frame), [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe) u [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/object) en una página alojada en otro servidor diferente (Servidor B).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Si tienes acceso al servidor que sirve la página que deseas incrustar en un marco, debes establecer la configuración en el mismo de la siguiente manera:

- Servidor que sirve la página para ser mostrada en un marco: `https://servidorA.com`
- Servidor que sirve la página con el elemento de marco: `https://servidorB.com`
- Configuración (Apache Servidor A): `Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://servidorB.com"`

En cualquier página de Servidor B podrás tener un marco que podrá efectivamente cargar una página de Servidor A.

Esto se traduce en que si no tienes acceso a la configuración del Servidor A, desde el cual quieres incrustar una página en un marco alojado en un Servidor B, no hay forma ni manera de que lo puedas hacer funcionar.

Por ejemplo, la página del famoso motor de búsquedas [Google](https://www.google.com) no permite que sus páginas sean cargadas en marcos de otras páginas en otros servidores que no sean de Google, o tal vez incluso ni siquiera de su propio servidor.

En cambio, sitios como [Youtube](https://youtube.com) o [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.com) si que permiten esto:

```html
<h4>Google en Marco</h4>
<iframe width="600" height="315" src="https://www.google.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<br>
<h4>Wikipedia en Marco</h4>
<iframe width="600" height="315" src="https://www.wikipedia.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<br>
<h4>Mi sitio en Marco</h4>
<iframe width="600" height="315" src="https://omnipc.ddns.net" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

He puesto 3 ejemplos: el primero es el sitio de Google, como y alo mencioné, el segundo es de Wikipedia, y el tercero es mi sitio personal, el cual tengo configurado con la cabecera `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`.

Por lo tanto, a menos que tengas acceso a la configuración del Servidor A, no hay nada que puedas hacer para mostrar la página del Servidor A en un marco en tu sitio alojado en un Servidor B.

Espero que esto te ayude a entender el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias es correcto! 
Ya me he puesto en contacto con el proveedor y dueños del sitio.